# Restore iPad to factory-default

Tags: ipad, restore

How to make iPad back to factory default without iTunes, restrictions code, iCloud, or backup. I want everything erased so I can completely start over.

Answer (score 1):

Without using iTunes, you can go to Settings > General > Reset, and click **reset/erase all content and settings**:

[image]

<sup>It's iOS 7, but it's the same for every version.</sup>

If you do it this way, it will prompt you for both your password and restrictions passcode several times.